# How to convert a set of formulas in CNF, S'

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to convert the formula:

S = { p, p → ((q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(q ∧ r)), p → ((s ∨ t) ∧ ¬(s ∧ t)), s → q, ¬r → t, t → s }

I understand I need to apply a→b to  ¬a v b in one of the instances, but it has 3, not 2, I'm unsure how it will lead to the answer containing 3 clauses.

Thanks.

EDIT after @Bram28 's help:

this is the answer: Consider the set of formulas

S = { p, p → ((q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(q ∧ r)), p → ((s ∨ t) ∧ ¬(s ∧ t)), s → q, ¬r → t, t → s }

(a) Transform S into a set of formulas in CNF, S'

P stays the same since any atomic statement in isolation is in CNF

p → ((q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(q ∧ r))
≡ (¬p ∨ q ∨ r) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬(q ∧ r) )
≡ (¬p ∨ q ∨ r) ∧ (¬p ∨ ( (¬q) ∨ (¬r) )

p → ((s ∨ t) ∧ ¬(s ∧ t))
≡ ¬p v ((s ∨ t) ∧ ¬(s ∧ t))
≡ (¬p v s ∨ t) ∧ (¬p v ¬s v ¬t)

Comment: What is the $S'$ in your title? What 'has 3, not 2'?  And why should the answer contain $3$ clauses?  Anyway, you're right, you should apply the equivalence you indicate .. a few DeMorgan's seem to be in order as well .... why don't you try that and see what happens.  Better yet, post your work!

Comment: don't mind about the S, I guess is my way of putting 1, 2, 3, ..

could you help me on how to do it? This is a very confusing topic

Comment: for example: would this one:  p → ((q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(q ∧ r))  be:

¬p v ((q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(q ∧ r))
and then I was thinking about the Distributive Laws but it doesn't apply here

Comment: No problem .. I can help ... so yes, try to convert that one. Make sure you show the steps.

Comment: for example: would this one:  p → ((q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(q ∧ r))  be:

¬p v ((q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(q ∧ r))
and then I was thinking about the Distributive Laws but it doesn't apply here

Comment: Sure it does!  Distribute the $\neg p \lor$ over the conjunction on the right, so you get $(\neg p \lor q \lor r) \land (\neg p \lor \neg (q \land r))$.  Now you need to do a DeMorgan on the $\neg ( q \land r)$

Comment: So it would be:

p → ((q ∨ r) ∧ ¬(q ∧ r))
≡(¬p ∨ q ∨ r) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬(q ∧ r) )
≡(¬p ∨ q ∨ r) ∧ (¬p ∨ ( (¬q) ∨ (¬r) )

So far so good?

How do you insert spaces here? lol so we can see it better

Comment: Yes, you got it! So that one is now in CNF. How about the others?

Comment: I was thinking about p, it stays the same, right?

Comment: @Arture Yes, any atomic statement in isolation is in CNF, so stays the same

Comment: p → ((s ∨ t) ∧ ¬(s ∧ t)) would be:

≡ ¬p v ((s ∨ t) ∧ ¬(s ∧ t))

is that right? and can we apply the Associative Laws on the second part?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: No, use Distribution again.  Notice how this statement has the exact same form as that first one you did.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?  What do you mean you want to "convert" the set.  Also what does the title mean?

Comment: True, so it would be:

p → ((s ∨ t) ∧ ¬(s ∧ t)) would be:

≡ ¬p v ((s ∨ t) ∧ ¬(s ∧ t))
≡ (¬p v s ∨ t) ∧ (¬p v ¬s v ¬t)

Is it correct master? haha

Comment: @Arturo Yes, that's correct! OK, the last ones should be easy. Why don't you post all of that in your original post .. also, since it seems like you need to convert it to a bunch of clauses, list what those clauses are.

Comment: I did edited the main post. So the last one should be:
___
s → q
≡ ¬s v q
___
¬r → t
≡ r v t
___
t → s 
≡ ¬t v s

Correct?